# Sorting List alphabetically from JSON source

Tags: javascript, android, list, http, sorting

I've looked in a variety of places for an answer to my query, but nothing has helped me thus far. I'm currently trying to learn Android development, and i'm stuck on how to sort a list alphabetically. I am using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/) on how to create the list and have modified parts of the "Albums" page to suit my needs, from albums to artists (i'm still working on this, just wanting the sorting finished before changing it fully). This particular list calls on a file from a HTTP address when the app is accessed to check it for updates.

Here is the code from that particular page, minus all the imports:

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {
// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;

// albums JSONArray
JSONArray albums = null;

// albums JSON url
private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/albums.php";

// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check for internet connection
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Hashmap for ListView
    albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
    new LoadAlbums().execute();

    // get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    /**
     * Listview item click listener
     * TrackListActivity will be lauched by passing album id
     * */
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // on selecting a single album
            // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

            // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
            String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all Albums by making http request
 * */
class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Listing Artists...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Albums JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {               
            albums = new JSONArray(json);

            if (albums != null) {
                // looping through All albums
                for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item values in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);



                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    albumsList.add(map);


                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }



    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList,
                        R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {
                                R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

My problem is that I have no real idea where I need to put the `Collections.sort` command. I have tried in so many places, but cannot get it working. No matter where I put the command, it always sorts in order of ID. This is the full code I have for that:

```
Collections.sort(params, new Comparator<NameValuePair>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(NameValuePair art1, NameValuePair art2) {
                     //here getTitle() method return app name...
                return art1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(art2.getName());

            }
});
```

If I try to have `return art1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(art2.name);` it comes back with an error that says *name cannot be resolved or is not a field*. I'm really stumped. I thought a list might be a good way to start learning to develop for Android, but now i'm finding this incredibly hard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like Java, not Javascript